# Как определит входит входит ли точка с координатами в радиус

Tags: php, java, laravel

Cоздаю сайт для волонтеров помогающим бездомным животным.
У каждого волонтера есть координаты широта и долгота, а также радиус например 10 км.
То есть гео точка это центр.
Есть база с животными и их координаты, как определить входит ли животное в радиус волонтера.
Как реализовать на `php` сам алгоритм и на `java` без сторонах библиотек, сайт на `Laravel`.

Comment: Вопрос, следует закрыть, так-как, непонятна суть вопроса. [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Есть база с животными и их координаты, как определить входит ли животное в радиус волонтера?Что не понятного

Comment: Вам следует прочитать справку, и сделать минимально рабочий пример (коды, запросы), а также описать, что у вас не получается, как пытались делать, какие возникли ошибки если они есть и т. д., Здесь не решают за вас задачи, которые вы сами не в состоянии написать.

Comment: Посчитайте расстояние между животным и волонтером. Если оно меньше радиуса, то входит. Если не меньше - не входит.

Comment: @Николай Следуйте совету tym32167.

Comment: Стояла бы Земля на трех китах и черепахе, - не было бы проблем. Но она, зараза, круглая. Т. о., нужна сферическая тригонометрия.
Вот здесь приводится нужная формула:
http://osiktakan.ru/geo_koor.htm

Comment: Найти расстояние между двумя точками в крайнем случае можно и через теорему пифагора (сумма квадратов катетов = квадрат гипотенузы) 
например:
Волонтер стоит на 30:30, собака на 25:25, радиус - 10
ищем прямой угол(думаю справишься) - 30:25
итог длина катетов: 5 и 5, вычисляешь гипотенузу и проверяешь меньше она радиуса или нет.
Для удобства можешь использовать листочек в клетку

Comment: @RuslanGorbunov Проблема в том, что используются географические координаты. Длинна одного градуса широты постоянна, а вот один градус долготы уменьшается с увеличением широты.